# Смена background с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку как правильно решить задачку. Есть inputs при нажатии на которые мы получаем value 'red,blue...' Есть button который должен проверить если выбран соответствующий input соответственно установить соответствующий цвет фона. Пока знаний хватило что бы цвет неважно какой input выбран менялся на красный. Спасибо за понимание)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Работа с радиокнопками</h1>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-secondary active bg-danger">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="red"> Красный
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary bg-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"  value="blue"> Синий
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary bg-success">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"  value="green"> Зеленый
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" id="checks">Применить</button>
        </div>

    var radio = document.getElementsByName('options');
    for ( var i=0; i<radio.length; i++ ){
        radio[i].onchange = f2;
    }
    function f2() {
        console.log(this.value);
    //Получаем this.value

    }
    document.getElementById('checks').onclick = checkRadio;

    function checkRadio() {
        var b = document.getElementsByName('options');
        for ( var i=0; i<b.length; i++){
            if ( b[i].checked ){
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все было очень просто)
document.body.style.backgroundColor = b[i].value